# Dijkstra Algorithm on a graph modeling a network

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

We have a directed graph `G = (V, E)` for a comm. network with each edge having a probability of not failing `r(u, v)` (defined as edge weight) which lies in interval [0, 1]. The probabilities are independent, so that from one vertex to another, if we multiply all probabilities, we get the the probability of the entire path not failing.

I need an efficient algorithm to find a most reliable path from one given vertex to another given vertex (i.e., a path from the first vertex to the second that is least likely to fail). I am given that `log(r · s) = log r + log s` will be helpful.

This is what I have so far -:

```
DIJKSTRA-VARIANT (G, s, t)
for v in V:
    val[v] ← ∞
A ← ∅
Q ← V to initialize Q with vertices in V.
val[s] ← 0
while Q is not ∅ and t is not in A
    do x ← EXTRACT-MIN (Q)
    A ← A ∪ {x}
    for each vertex y ∈ Adj[x]
        do if val[x] + p(x, y) < val[y]:
           val[y] = val[x] + p(x, y)
```

`s` is the source vertex and `t` is the destination vertex. Of course, I have not exploited the `log` property as I am not able to understand how to use it. The **relaxation** portion of the algorithm at the bottom needs to be modified, and the `val` array will capture the results. Without log, it would probably be storing the next highest probability. How should I modify the algorithm to use `log`?

Comment: How well do you understand Dijkstra? Do you know what problem it solves? Do you see the difference between that problem and the one you've been given? *Now* do you see how the log property might be useful?

Comment: 1. "How well do you understand Dijkstra?" - A bit.
2. "Do you know what problem it solves?" - It solves the problem of finding the shortest paths for a single source.
3. "What is the difference between the problems?" - Edge weights are probabilities in the range [0, 1]. To find a most reliable path from one vertex to another, I must multiply probabilities and get the highest for a path.
4. "Do you see how `log` could be used?" - It is this that I fail to understand.

Comment: Oh wait...since I must multiply probabilities, should I be using `log` to maintain a summation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your code has

```
do if val[x] + p(x, y) < val[y]:
    val[y] = val[x] + p(x, y)
```

Since the edge weights in this case represent probabilities, you need to multiply them together (rather than adding):

```
do if val[x] * p(x, y) > val[y]:
    val[y] = val[x] * p(x, y)
```

I've changed the sign to `>`, since you want the probability to be as large as possible.

Logs are helpful because (1) `log(xy) = log(x) + log(y)` (as you said) and sums are easier to compute than products, and (2) `log(x)` is a monotonic function of `x`, so `log(x)` and `x` have their maximum in the same place.  Therefore, you can deal with the logarithm of the probability, instead of the probability itself:

```
do if log_val[x] + log(p(x, y)) > log_val[y]:
    log_val[y] = log_val[x] + log(p(x, y))
```

Edited to add (since I don't have enough rep to leave a comment): you'll want to initialize your `val` array to `0`, rather than `Infinity`, because you're calculating a maximum instead of a minimum.  (Since you want the **largest** probability of **not** failing.)   So, after log transforming, the initial `log_val` array values should be `-Infinity`.

Comment: For the sake of convenience, I can use `-Infinity` in the algorithm then?

Comment: Yep -- just change the initial `val[v] = -Infinity`, use `log(p(x,y))` in place of `p(x,y)`, and change the `<` to a `>` and you should be good to go.  And, I think I may have just done your homework assignment for you, but oh well :)

Comment: Well, at least I tried, unlike most other people. I believe `val[s]` should be 1, and on applying `log` I would get a 0. I say 1 because vertex `s` is already in the bag, and 1 represents the highest probability possible. It is analogous to 0 in a normal implementation of Dijkstra.

Comment: Btw, the one thing I didn't tell you is what `val[s]` should be! I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: This is very late, but will the above solution work when there are cycles?

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate probabilities you should multiply (instead of add) in the relaxation phase, which means changing:

```
do if val[x] + p(x, y) < val[y]:
           val[y] = val[x] + p(x, y)
```

to:

```
do if val[x] * p(x, y) < val[y]:
           val[y] = val[x] * p(x, y)
```

Using the Log is possible if the range is (0,1] since log(0) = -infinity and log(1) = 0, it means that for every `x,y in (0,1]`: 
`probability x < probability y` than: 
`log(x) < log(y)`. 
Since we are maintaining the same relation (between probabilities) this modification will provide the correct answer.

I think you'll be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have solved the question partially.

Here is my attempt. Edits and pointers are welcome -:

```
DIJKSTRA-VARIANT (G, s, t)
for v in V:
    val[v] ← 0
A ← ∅
Q ← V to initialize Q with vertices in V.
val[s] ← 1
while Q is not ∅ and t is not in A
    do x ← EXTRACT-MAX (Q)
    A ← A ∪ {x}
    for each vertex y ∈ Adj[x]
        do if log(val[x]) + log(p(x, y)) > log(val[y]):
           log(val[y]) = log(val[x]) + log(p(x, y))
```

Since I am to find the highest possible probability values, I believe I should be using `>`. The following questions remain -:

1. What should the initial values in the `val` array be?
2. Is there anything else I need to add?

EDIT: I have changed the initial `val` values to 0. However, `log` is undefined at 0. I am open to a better alternative. Also, I changed the priority queue's method to `EXTRACT-MAX` since it is the larger probabilities that need to be extracted. This would ideally be implemented on a `binary max-heap`.

FURTHER EDIT: I have marked tinybike's answer as accepted, since they have posted most of the necessary details that I require. The algorithm should be as I have posted here.